# Ruby what is join ==

Tags: ruby

I know about the join method (e.g. array.join(" ") or array.join("_")) which will put elements of an array (or i believe a hash) together. However I came across an example from the solution to a problem i've been working on and it looks like this:

```
def find(hash_key)
    @options.select { |key,value| key.scan(hash_key).join == hash_key }
end
```

I understand it completely until the .join == hash_key part.

Can someone please explain this to me :D

Comment: list.join('') is the same thing as list.join. In ruby, parentheses on function calls are optional.

Comment: @Close voter: How is this primarily opinion-based?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@options.select {
```

This will select the items in `@options`...

```
key.scan(hash_key).join == hash_key
```

Where `key.scan(hash_key).join` is equal to `hash_key`.

This can also be written, more clearly, as:

```
@options.select { |key,value| key.scan(hash_key).join() == hash_key }
```

(If `join` is not provided an argument, it assumes `""` (an empty string).

Comment: ah ok thats so simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
join(separator=$,) → str
Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string, separated by the given separator. If the separator is nil, it uses current $,. If both the separator and $, are nil, it uses empty string.

[ "a", "b", "c" ].join        #=> "abc"
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join("-")   #=> "a-b-c"
```

http://zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html says that `$,` is "The output field separator for the print and Array#join. Defaults to nil.".